# Cakephp multilanguage support in Javascript

Tags: cakephp

How to give language strings in js while using cakephp (Im using cakephp version 2) ? I know, this can be done in the following way.

```
<script>
     var LABEL_LOGIN = '<?php echo __('Login'); ?>';
</script>
```

I want to separate my js code from my view file. Anything wrong if I do the same in .js file (because I am using global vars) ? Is there any other good solution to apply multilanguage in js ?

Comment: you wont be able to use php in your .js file..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cake does not support i18n in JS out of the box. I would rather recommend pulling in some i18n JS plugin which is syntactically compatible, i.e. also uses a global __ function.
Then you coul use the same method to parse all source codes for i18n keys.

Answer (score 0):

The only easier way i could think of is:

```
Create some element, say langs.ctp, and add your global js vars in there, like
<script type="text/javascript">
var LABEL_LOGIN = '<?php echo __('Login'); ?>';
var LABEL_LOGOUT = '<?php echo __('Logout'); ?>'; // and so on
</script>

and then load this element in your layout, like, in your layout inside head tag
<?php echo $this->element("langs");

then you could use your global js vars
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks for the help.. But I need to separate my js from my view file.. In this approach, if for registration, do I need to create another ctp file for registration language strings ? Because, I can't load all language strings in one ctp file..

Comment: Yea, you could create different ctp's for adding view specific js variables and then use in specific pages respectively, that would eliminate the need to add all variables in a single ctp file..